# Download Stream with RestSharp and ResponseWriter

Tags: http, stream, http-status-codes, restsharp

I donwnload a stream with RestSharp by using the ResponseWriter.

```
var client = new RestClient
var request = new RestRequest();
// ...
request.ResponseWriter = (ms) => {
  // how to detect the status code
};
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

How can I found out the HTTP Status Code in the ResponseWriter? 
Is there a better way to download a Stream?

Comment: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started . "If you need access to the HTTP status code returned you will find it at RestResponse.StatusCode"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check response.StatusCode and response.StatusDescription after executing the request.

Interestingly, if you use the DownloadData method as described here https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Other-Usage-Examples there is no way to access this information as far as I can tell.

Comment: The given link yields no example as expected

Answer (score 1):

Currently You can use property **AdvancedResponseWriter** instead ResponseWriter.

The main difference is that AdvancedResponseWriter in addition to Response Stream gets IHttpResponse and You can check Response Status.

It should be working properly from version 106.6.
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1207